# Please tell me the mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have say 5 tables,
`user , t1, t2, t3, t4`
`user` has a field called `id`.
`t1` to `t4` all have a corresponding field called `user_id`, and a field called `verification`.

Now I need to distinctly(or uniquely) select the `user` from `user table`, whose `id` exists at least once in at least one table among `t1` to `t4`,and where the `verification` field is `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From you detail description it looks that you are near solution. The EXISTS and OR need to be used (assuming that TRUE replaced with 1):

```
SELECT id FROM User u WHERE
    EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t1 WHERE u.id = t1.user_id AND t1.verification =1) 
    OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE u.id = t2.user_id AND t2.verification =1 )
    OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t3 WHERE u.id = t3.user_id AND t3.verification =1 ) 
    OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t4 WHERE u.id = t4.user_id AND t4.verification =1 )
```

Comment: This has a few issues, performance and incorrect column names, `u.user_id` doesn't exist for example, it's `u.id`....as the *other* part of the query has :)

Comment: so it's id in one table and user_id in others - hey that's sensible !!

Comment: @Nick Craver - EXISTS has higher performance over UNION. Since EXISTS need to locate only single entry, while UNION expects large set manipulation. It is also well known that in most SQL implementation EXISTS is more preferable than IN.

Comment: That's true *in general*, but in cases of a single column (optimally a union of indexes here), it's a *very* different performance comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Tedious rather than difficult:

```
SELECT id FROM User JOIN t1 ON user.id = t1.user_id WHERE verification = TRUE
UNION
SELECT id FROM User JOIN t2 ON user.id = t2.user_id WHERE verification = TRUE
UNION
SELECT id FROM User JOIN t3 ON user.id = t3.user_id WHERE verification = TRUE
UNION
SELECT id FROM User JOIN t4 ON user.id = t4.user_id WHERE verification = TRUE
```

Comment: You would need `UNION DISTINCT` to get the desired result with this approach.

Comment: @Nick:  Please explain...UNION ALL preserves duplicates; UNION alone eliminates duplicates; UNION DISTINCT is non-standard because it is implied by simple UNION.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [`UNION` set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) on the `t1`-`t4` tables to get the `user_id` in those, and use that result for a [`IN()` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) on the `user` table, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id FROM t1 WHERE verification = TRUE
             UNION
             SELECT user_id FROM t2 WHERE verification = TRUE
             UNION
             SELECT user_id FROM t3 WHERE verification = TRUE
             UNION
             SELECT user_id FROM t4 WHERE verification = TRUE)'
```

Just by the nature of how `IN()` works, you get distinct `user` table results as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
       distinct u.user
from
       user u
where
      exists (
      (select user_id from t1 where t1.user_id  = u.id and t1.verification = true)
   OR (select user_id from t2 where t2.user_id  = u.id and t2.verification = true)
   OR (select user_id from t3 where t3.user_id  = u.id and t3.verification = true)
   OR (select user_id from t4 where t4.user_id  = u.id and t4.verification = true)
   )
```